# Why puts() prints some garbage values on output in C

Tags: c, c-strings, palindrome, garbage, function-definition

I'm trying to do a function in C language that it's checking if a String is palindromic (read the same way from the begging to the end and backwards ) . So I use the `puts()` function to print the String backwards and after a number of elements (>7) it prints some unwanted characters.

My routine is :

```
void isPal ( char ptr[], int i){


    char array[i];

    int j=0,k=0;
    int l = i-1;

    for (j=0; j<i ; j++){
        array[j] = ptr[l]; printf("%c\t", array[j] );

        printf("Character :%c -> [%d]\n", array[j],l );
        l--; 
    }

    printf("\nThe upside string is : ");
    puts(array);


    for (k=0; k<i ; k++){
        if ( array[k] != ptr[k]){

            printf("\nNot palindromic!!!\n");
            return; 
        }
    }
    printf("\nIS PALINDROMIC..\n");
}
```

The result is accurate but the printing isn't right . Why that ?

Comment: What specific values of `ptr` and `i` are you calling your function with? And what exactly does it print?

Comment: Is `char array[i];` how you usually allocate memory in C? You should be using `malloc` for dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Cheatah: It's legal and reasonably safe if the value of `i` is fairly small.  I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: The value of `i` in this code is important, and your should provide a proper [mcve] in your question. Regardless, not sure why you're even using a copy to check for palindrome state in the first place. two pointers walking up/down the input string until they meet/pass should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The created array does not contain a string because there is no the terminating zero in the array.

Also there is no need to define an auxiliary array to determine whether the passed string is a palindrome.

Creating a variable length array within the function is unsafe and can result in a stack overflow. Apart from this the user of the function can pass to the function the second argument less than or equal to 0. In this case the function will have undefined behavior.

The function should do only one thing i.e. to determine whether the passed string is a palindrome.

It is the caller of the function that will decide what message to output if any.

The function parameter that specifies the array should have the qualifier `const` because the passed string is not being changed in the function.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int isPal ( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n-i-1] ) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPal ( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n-i-1] ) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "123454321";

    printf( "The string \"%s\" is %sa palindrome.\n",
            s, isPal( s ) ? "" : "not " );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
The string "123454321" is a palindrome.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `char array[i];` with following two lines:

```
char array[i+1];
array[i] = '\0';
```

`puts()` takes `string` as an argument. In c, string is basically a character array with `'\0'` at the end. So, when we add `'\0'` at the end of `array[]` it becomes a string and as a result `puts()` does not show any unpredictable behaviour.